# Modify an SVG file based on information in a CSV file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, csv, xml, svg

I've got a SVG file of the map of the US and I want to add colors to it. Because it would take me to much time, I thought I could use a bash script. I have also another file containing the states and the colors that belong to them.

SVG-file:

```
<g id="hi">
    <title>Hawaii</title>
    <path class="state hi" d="m 233.08751,519.30948 ... z" id="HI" />
</g>
```

CSV-file

```
HI, blue
```

What I want:

```
<g id="hi" style="fill:blue;">
        <title>Hawaii</title>
        <path class="state hi" d="m 233.08751,519.30948 ... z" id="HI" />
    </g>
```

I thought I could use `grep` or `sed` but I really don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bash and GNU sed:

```
while IFS=",$IFS" read id color
do
    sed -i "s/g id=\"${id,,}\"/& style=\"fill:$color;\"/g" file.svg
done <file.csv
```

After this is done, file.svg looks like:

```
<g id="hi" style="fill:blue;">
    <title>Hawaii</title>
    <path class="state hi" d="m 233.08751,519.30948 ... z" id="HI" />
</g>
```

#### How it works

- `while IFS=",$IFS" read id color; do`

  This starts a `while` loop by reading the variables `id` and `color`.  We add a comma to `IFS` so that the input is split on commas as well as whitespace.
- `sed -i "s/g id=\"${id,,}\"/& style=\"fill:$color;\"/g" file.svg`

  This does an in-place update of file.svg.  This uses bash to convert `id` to lower case: `${id,,}`.  It looks for the string `g id="${id,,}"` and replaces it with `g id="${id,,} style="fill:$color;"`.

  Note: `$id` and `$color` are substituted directly into a sed command.  You should do this *only if* you trust the source of the file.csv file.
- `done <file.csv`

  This concludes the `while` loop and instructs it to read from `file.csv`.

#### BSD (OSX)

If you are on a BSD system, we need to make a slight change to the sed command:

```
while IFS=",$IFS" read id color
do
    sed -i "" "s/g id=\"${id,,}\"/& style=\"fill:$color;\"/g" file.svg
done <file.csv
```

Comment: but the shell gives me this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unterminated `s' command

Comment: That would indicate a missing final `/`.  Try copying-and-pasting again to make sure that the command is correct.  Also, are you using the same `file.csv` in the question or a different one?  If a different one, let me see the contents.

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl and its [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)
:

```
perl {
    open my $FH, '<', 'states.csv' or die $!;
    $h->{lc $1} = "$2;" while <$FH> =~ /(.*),\s*(.*)/;
};

open map.xml ;
for //g set @style concat("fill:", xsh:lookup('h', @id));
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

using sed, twice:

```
</tmp/states.csv tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" | \
sed -n 's/^\([a-z]\{2\}\), \([^ ]*\)$/s@<g id="\1">@<g id="\1" style="fill:\2;">@/p' >/tmp/script.sed
sed -f /tmp/script.sed /tmp/source.svg
```

The first line creates a sed script (/tmp/script.sed) and the second line implements it. Assumes that your list of states is saved at /tmp/states.csv and your svg file at /tmp/source.svg.

Comment: @mikeserv, OP has told us what is in the csv, It could be modified to work if there is other stuff in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr   \[:upper:] \[:lower:] <csv.file | sort -bt, -uk1,1   |
sed  -e'\|^ *\([[:alpha:]]\{2\}\) *, *\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}\) *$|!d' \
     -e's||s/\\(<g id="\1"\\)>/\\1 style="fill:\2;">/;t|' |
sed  -f- svg.file
```